# How many ways to operate MS word document in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

I wish to know is there someother way that allow us to operate MS word in C#.NET platform. Or that we can only use Office.Interop to achieve that?

I am kind of confused to that. Can you explain some skills or resource for me to find out step by step. Thanks.

I can handle "Interop" myself or by googling it. I wish to know something new to me, so I can find out with your explanation.  Any idea?

Comment: With "operate" do you mean "edit the files of", or are you trying something else?

Comment: I want to edit the document, like do formatting, or copy content?

Comment: I have done all the basic stuff like copying, deleting, moving text, adding headers and footers, page numbers, toc, styling using office.interop. I felt it is comfortable. Didnt tried new.

Comment: I know it is quite easy to edit document in Office.interop.  But what if we move our solution to a moblie or somewhere that MS word is not on.  What should we do next?

Comment: You can, for instance, treat Excel files like databases by using OleDB instead of Interop. But I'm not sure that is the solution for you. Are you sure you need MS-Office files in an environment where you don't have MS-Office?

Comment: What I am trying to know is that can we have a workaround of office.interop? if yes, then  i wish to hear a little about it,  so i can search it to find more about it.  That is what i want.  Am I too stupid to ask such a stuff?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to operate with Microsoft Word documents without Office and Interop.

1. OpenXML
2. 3rd party components

**OpenXML**

All what you need for it is [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee330856). There are set of .NET classes thre that allows you to completely manipulate or create Word documents, of course in OpenXML fomat -  docx. For example googled [video on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/donovanf/Introduction-to-Open-XML-SDK-20-Solution-Development-Part-2) with intro to OpenXML link for you to start, and [article](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/06/02/4730.aspx) about it.

Using OpenXML is considered as a low level way to manipulate docx

**3rd party components**

For example, on several my projects we have used [Aspose components](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). It can make development easier and is not bound only to OpenXML format, so you can manipulate doc/docx. But with OpenXML you have full control on what your code is producing and with 3rd parties you are depending from external components, that in some rare situations can generate not what you are expecting.

I'm sure there are many other 3rd parties. But Aspose is that, I've used on 2 production projects, and it seems to be good enough for them.

You can look at Aspose [demos](http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.words/default.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Regfor. Thanks.  your solution is good with me except that the aspose cost so much.

Comment: Yes, they cost to much. But for production project they looks good and have good support. To reduce costs I suggest to use OpenXML and look for some open-source code to make routine tasks with OpenXML easier